# Variance of n-dimensional random vector

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Z_1, Z_2, \ldots, Z_k$ of $Z$ i.i.d. in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A sample mean

\begin{equation}
\bar{Z}_k = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j
\end{equation}

by the strong law of large numbers is

\begin{equation}
\bar{Z}_k \to x 
\end{equation}

almost surely as $k \to \infty$.

Computing the variance of $\bar{Z}_k$ we get

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j &=\\
Var\left( \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j \right) &=\\
\mathbb{E}  \left( \left\| x - \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j \right\|_2^2 \right) &= \\
\frac{1}{k^2} \mathbb{E} \left( \left\| \sum_{j=1}^k (Z_j -x ) \right\|_2^2 \right)
\end{align}

How can I obtain the last equality? Is that correct?

Based on answer given, I will reproduce the last equality steps below.

Since $x$ can be rewritten as

\begin{equation}
x = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k x
\end{equation}

we obtain:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}  \left( \left\| x - \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j \right\|_2^2 \right) &=\\
\mathbb{E}  \left( \left\| \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k x - \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j \right\|_2^2 \right) &=\\
\mathbb{E}  \left( \left\| \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k \left( x - Z_j \right) \right\|_2^2 \right) &=\\
\mathbb{E}  \left( \left\| -\frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k \left( Z_j - x \right) \right\|_2^2 \right) &=\\
\left( -\frac{1}{k} \right)^2 \mathbb{E}  \left( \left\|  \sum_{j=1}^k \left( Z_j - x \right) \right\|_2^2 \right) &=\\
\frac{1}{k^2} \mathbb{E}   \left( \left\|  \sum_{j=1}^k \left( Z_j - x \right) \right\|_2^2 \right) 
\end{align}
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x - \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k Z_j $ is same as $-\frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k (Z_j-x)$ since $\frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^k x=x$. The last step is valid (since $\frac 1 k$ can be pulled out).